# My version of PowerMod breaks down around 10^308

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, recursion, number-theory

I have been trying to write a function that duplicates `PowerMod[a, b, n]`, computing `a^b` mod `n`. I am currently testing using `3^x mod 353` and varying `x`. I have found that my results match that of the built-in function until I hit `x = 10^(308)`. At this point, I get a recursion limit error. Is there a reason this is occurring, considering Mathematica's built in function still works at these values?

```
pmod[a_, b_, mod_] := 
  Module[{l, z, binarylist = IntegerDigits[b, 2], val = 1},
    l = Length[binarylist];
    Clear[z];
    z[1] = a;
    z[j_] := z[j] = Mod[z[j - 1]^2, mod];
    z[l];
    Do[
      If[binarylist[[j]] == 1,
        val * = z[l - j + 1]; val = Mod[val, 
        mod]],
      {j, 1, l}]; 
    val]
```

I use `l - j + 1` because I want when `j = 1`, if binarylist[[j]] = 1; val *= z[j], when `j = 2`; want `val*=z[j - 1]`, ..., `j = l, val *=z[1]`. This is a consequence of Mathematica, lists starting at 1, not 0.

```
pmod[3, 10^305, 353]
```

> `140`

```
PowerMod[3, 10^305, 353]
```

> `140`

```
pmod[3, 10^308, 353]
```

> \$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Mod[z$50178[4-1]^2,353].
>
> `185`

```
PowerMod[3, 10^308, 353]
```

> `58`

#### Edit

I thought this may be due to 10^308 exceeding 2^1024, but my math shows that happens at 10^309. If I should be using 2^1023 ( I don't see why i would be, but I may just be overthinking this), then that explains the error. ( It isn't GREATER than 2^1024, but including 0 in the array of the digits gives it 1024 elements. See my answer to my question below.)

Comment: There are better ways to implement the Russian peasant algorithm, but as a starting point: `z = Reverse[NestList[Mod[#^2, mod] &, a, l - 1]];` and then do `val *= z[[j]]` within your loop.

Comment: I know this isn't the best way, I was just curious why it was breaking down. I added some bits at the end explaining what my first thought on the issue may have been. I will implement your suggestions, and see if it stills breaks. Thanks :)

Comment: The warning message is pretty informative; your implementation has a recursive computation of `z` that is hitting the current limit. If you want to do an experiment, try `Block[{$RecursionLimit = 2048}, pmod[3, 10^308, 353]]`.

Comment: That is where My original thought at the error came from, considering 10^308 may  have been (i believe, with the inclusion of 2^0=1 in binary, it is the cause of the error), and hence the list  binarylist was greater than or equal to 1024, exceeding the recursion limit. I'll try modifying that limit now, as you suggested.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less  That was the problem. I can either post an answer to my own question, or allow you to point out via your own answer that I was just exceeding $RecursionLimit by having a number that when expressed in binary, had >= 1024 digits. Either way, thanks, I probably could have figured this out eventually, though who knows how long. (if you are computer less, do you just remember all this stuff? I know, bad joke.)

Comment: Yes, you answering your own question would be good, if you got it. If you want a further diagnostic, insert the line `Echo[Length[DownValues[z]]];` after your call to `z[l];`, and look what happens to your original call with the default `$RecursionLimit` setting of `1024`, and when you increase the limit. (Yes, I'm doing these things from a smartphone.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies in that Mathematica has a built in limit to the depth of it's recursion, which is `1024`. So we cannot, without changing that limit calculate the values of `z[1024]`,`z[1025]`, etc. This can be changed by inserting at the beginning of the code within Module, a recursion limit greater than `1024` (I chose `$RecursionLimit=2*1024`). The reason this occurs at `10^308` is because the binary expansion of `10^308` has `1024` digits, the limit for recursion within Mathematica. A working code(up to `2048` binary digits, of course), is provided below:

```
pmod[a_, b_, mod_] := Module[{l, z, binarylist = IntegerDigits[b, 2], val = 1},
  $RecursionLimit=1024*2;
  l = Length[binarylist];
  Clear[z];
  z[1] = a;
  z[j_]:=z[j]= Mod[z[j - 1]^2, mod];
  z[l];
  Do[
    If[
        binarylist[[j]] == 1,
           val *= z[l-j+1]; val = Mod[val, mod]],
  {j, 1, l}];  
    val]
```

There are, however, more efficient way to implement this function, which I suspect will show it self as the number of digits increases to very large amounts, as those are likely to be implemented by the inherent `PowerMod` function built-in to Mathematica.

Comment: It's often not a good idea to set `$RecursionLimit` too high globally; if you must do so, localize it in a `Block[]`, so you have something like `Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1024*2}, Module[(* stuff *)]]`. Even then, all you have done is to delay the problem to `b == 10^616` or so.

Comment: Just for your reference, here's is one way to (compactly) do the Russian peasant method: `pmod[a_, b_, mod_] := Fold[Mod[If[#2 == 1, a #, #] #, mod] &, 1, IntegerDigits[b, 2]]`.

Comment: I was indeed slightly worried about globally setting `$RecursionLimit` too high. I forgot that module does not automatically localize all the settings changes you make (I've only had to deal with changing $Option values probably half a dozen times). I realize all this does it delay the problem. I'll have to find a way to parse how Mathematica itself has this defined, as if I recall correctly, almost all numbers(maybe even all?) begin to exhibit a pattern that can be utilized to shorten this process. . I would expect that to greatly increase the utility of such a function. Maybe something

Comment: along the lines of if a pattern is noticed ( such as z[k]=z[h], z[k+1]=z[h+1], etc), to just repeatedly add that to the end of the list until the length is reached. Interesting things to think about, nonetheless. I will try to parse your compact, code, I generally have a hard time parsing such things quickly as I don't use Mathematica too much, nor the compact syntax used within it.

Comment: If i am reading the compact code correctly, It takes each of the digits of `IntegerDigits[b,2]`, checks if they are one, and if it is, calculates a*1, if they are not, it just outputs 1. It then multiplies this by 1 again, and reduces modulo mod. This repeats until there are no digits left in `IntegerDigits[b,2]`. Am I close?

Comment: In general, in a situation like this, instead of a bare `z[l]` use `Do[z[k], {k,l}]` which does only one recursion step at a time. I do this a lot in my own code.

Comment: That is an interesting way to make this work without changing `$RecursionLimit`. Thanks for the input, @Somos